# Check if array member is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, boolean

When having a simple boolean, it is simple to use it in a condition :

```
var running = true;
if(running) {/*do something*/}
```

Is there some trick to do this with a boolen array? something like this:

```
var running = [false,false,true,false];
if(running[]){/*do something*/}
```

At the moment I do it like this :

```
var uploading = false
            for(i=0; i< running.length ; i++)
            {
                if(running[i]) uploading = true;
            }

            if(uploading)
```

But I feel like this is not really perfectly written code and that their could be some trick, shorthand method.. Could be plain javascript, could be Jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery has the `$.inArray` method:

```
uploading = $.inArray(running, true) !== -1;
```

The name is slightly misleading, it returns the index of the element that matched (`-1` if none).

JavaScript has `Array#indexOf`, but it's missing in IE8 and earlier:

```
uploading = running.indexOf(true) !== -1;
```

JavaScript as of ES5 has the `Array#some` method, but it's overkill if you can look for the specific value with either of the above. Still, it's useful if you need to massage the values at all. For instance, if any "truthy" value is okay rather than specifically `true`:

```
uploading = running.some(function(entry) { return !!entry; });
```

Comment: It's easy to include a polyfill for [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this:

```
uploading = running.indexOf(true) !== -1;
```

If the array doesn't contain a `true`, `indexOf` will return -1, resulting in a `false` from `!== -1`. If the array contains a `true`, `indexOf` will return it's index, resulting in a `true`.

A slightly shorter option:

```
uploading = !!~running.indexOf(true);
```

The `~` is a bitwise NOT, this inverts the value from indexOf: `-1 -> 0, 0 -> -1, 1 -> -2, etc`. Then the double `!` first casts this value to a boolean, then inverts it again, resulting in a boolean output that's `true` then the array contains a `true`.

Comment: `uploading = !!~running.indexOf(true)` if you want a boolean result

Comment: or `running.indexOf(true) > -1`.

Comment: Yea, if the `index` is `0`, that's still a `false`. A `!=` or some other operator seems necessary, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought about little trick that can work in this situation:

```
uploading = !!Math.max.apply(null, [false, true, false, false]); // => true
```

Basically without `!!` path you will get `1` (if there is at least one `true`) or `false` (for all `false` in array). `Max` calls `ToNumber` for each passed argument, so `true` => `1`.

Note: you'd better use `indexOf`, this is just for fun and to demonstrate another unobvious way.

Comment: _JavaScript, wat r u doin? JavaScript, stahp!_ I had no idea this was even close to possible :D